# ArrayList Confusion and assistance!

Tags: java, arraylist

basically id like a few hints or tips on how to solve this question.. maybe a few things which i could read up on about arraylists and loop which would make it simple for me to understand!..

the question is :

Processing an ArrayList of Characters:
    cList is an ArrayList of objects of type Character that has been declared and intialised. Write a loop that will count the Characters that are not spaces and print the number out to the terminal window.

and second question would be:

Looping through a String

Assuming that a variable has been declared like this:

```
String s;
```

and that a value has already been assigned to s, write a loop statement that will print the characters of s in reverse order (so if s = "HELLO", your loop should print "OLLEH").

for the first question i tried to do:

```
public ArrayList()
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int countBlank;
    char ch;
public ArrayList (int cList)      
{
    int cList = ;
    while(cList ){
        System.out.println(cList);
        }
        }
```

and second question :

i have no idea, but a read up would be great!

thank you!

Comment: no this isnt, its preperation for my exam, just seem to forgot quite a bit and need to re-read and learn.

Comment: to inverse a string you have to read from the back and reach the beginning ... try to do it alone, it doesn't need any help ;)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and doesn't really make sense...

Comment: i know, quite a few bits are missing, was just woundering anything i could read up on which could help me to understand it more easier so i could get this revision question correct

Comment: That's some serious..um..java.

Comment: At this point, I don't think some last-minute reading is going to help your Java skills whatsoever.

Comment: No offence, but please read up on basic Java syntax. Then read the javadoc on ArrayList. You seem very confused and lacking knowledge of the very the basics.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by reading up on [ArrayList Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and documentation on [mindprod](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/arraylist.html).

In your example you haven't declared cList as arraylist nor filled it with Character objects. Instead of a while you might look into `for`. To get the characters in a String, [String.toCharArray()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) might be of use.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you want to loop through the list and count the number of times a character isn't a space.

```
int counter = 0;
for (Character c : characters) {
    if (c == null {
        continue; // Note: You can have null values in an java.util.ArrayList
    }
    if (!Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

For your second question:

```
for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An arraylist is probably too fat for that:

```
import java.text.CharacterIterator;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;

public class CI {
    private static final String text = "Hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(text);

        for (char ch = it.last(); ch != CharacterIterator.DONE; ch = it
                .previous()) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops it was retagged as homework, I'm sorry to give a ready to run example

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Question 1:
import java.util.*;

public class ProcessListOfChars{

```
    public static int printCharsInListIgnoreSpaces(List<Character> cList){
            int count =0;
            for(Character character:cList){
            //      System.out.println("Value :"+character);
                    if(character!=null &&!character.toString().trim().equals("")){
                            ++count;
                    }
            }
            return count;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
            List<Character> cList = new ArrayList<Character>();
            cList.add('c'); //Autoboxed char to Charater Wrapper Class
            cList.add(' '); //Space character
            cList.add('r');
            cList.add('b');
            cList.add(' ');
            int count = printCharsInListIgnoreSpaces(cList);
            System.out.println("Count of Characers :"+count);
    }
```

}

Comment: hope this solves the first problem
second one is pretty simpler and i want you to think about it logically.

Comment: thank you for your help, but the compilation gives erros such as : 

Test.java:9: illegal start of expression
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    ^
Test.java:10: illegal start of expression
public class ProcessListOfChars{
^
Test.java:10: ';' expected
public class ProcessListOfChars{
       ^
3 errors